# Does the Linebreaker feat imply that the battlemind provokes an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, opportunity-attack, battlemind

> #### Linebreaker
>
> **Benefit:** When you use your *speed of thought*, you can enter an
>   enemy's space.  Doing so ends the movement.  You must then slide the
>   enemy 1 square.

Unless a Battlemind takes the **Zephyr Blade** paragon path, which allows *speed of thought* to avoid provoking **opportunity attacks**, then moving from a square adjacent to an enemy into an enemy's space should provoke an opportunity attack.

Does using Linebreaker cause an unmodified *speed of thought* move to provoke an opportunity attack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are leaving a square adjacent to your enemy. So yes under normal circumstances you would eat an opportunity attack from this movement.